# Sigabrt when using Notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an App in Swift.

So far so good, but I get a sigabrt and since there is not much documentation yet for Swift this is quite annoying.

Delegate: AppDelegate.swift

in func application ( ... ) { ... }

I do:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "saveMyItems:", name:"saveItems", object: nil)
```

I have seen the notion that it is important to have the colon after the selector method.

in class AppDelegate I also have the selector method:

```
func saveMyItems(notification: NSNotification){
    //Action take on Notification
    NSLog(" ======== Saving... ======== ")
}
```

Then in my ViewController I do:

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: AnyObject) {  
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("saveItems", object: nil)
}
```

I can't figure out what causes this so any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What are the details of the `SIGABRT` you're getting?  Do you have a stack trace and/or a detailed error message?

Comment: Hi Mike, I already solved it. It was not caused by the notification but the line just before: "NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("saveItems", object: nil)" I was just blind-staring on the notification pattern part and forgot to look at the simple line just before it! 

Swift is much better than Objective-C I think, only a pity that there aren't a lot of tutorials yet!

Comment: So what is this line before .postNotificationName that you fixed? I'm also getting a SIGABRT on that same function, and I don't have a "line just before" that that could cause this problem, so I'm pretty sure it's the postNotificationName().

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to see what I did a year ago to fix that line since I also changed more things. At the time I did not fully understand Swift yet (not that I do now fully understand, but at least have much better knowledge of such a constructions). You might have just forgotten the colon in the addObserver (or made a typo) and that will cause a sigabort when you post a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the selector from "saveItems" to "saveItems:" and it will work

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. If you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: actually this is an answer. The selector must have a colon (:) at the end to avoid getting this sigabrt error.